# Confusion about adding NSCoding to an existing project (new to C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was reading a tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager

about using NSCoding so that I can save my app data. Early on the tutorial modified the @interface line to look like this:

```
@interface ScaryBugData : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

My intent is to use NSCoding in my Delegate, but the @interface line already looks like this:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@end
```

Since I'm new to objective-c, I'm not sure how to combine the two in the same .h file.
(For that matter, I'm not clear on the syntax either.)

How would I combine and use the two statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an class conforms to more than one protocol, you can list them commaseperated like

```
<UIApplicationDelegate, NSCoding>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with delegates. *has more than one delegate* probably mean *conforms to more than one protocol*.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NSCoding> {...} ... @end
```

should do what you want, I think.